# msgpack over zeromq : c++ sender python receiver, how can I receive below message in python

Tags: python, zeromq, msgpack

C++ sending below struct msgpack over zeromq.

How can I deserialize from Python?

```cpp
msgpack::sbuffer serialize(cv::Mat &img, std::string &msg)
{
    Image img_data;
    img_data.matrix = std::vector<uchar>(img.data, img.data + (img.rows * img.cols * img.channels()));
    
    img_data.rows = img.rows;
    img_data.cols = img.cols;
    img_data.type = img.type();
    img_data.msg  = msg;
    
    msgpack::sbuffer serialized_img;
    msgpack::pack(&serialized_img, img_data);
    
    return serialized_img;
}
```

Receiving bytes:

```py
import zmq
import msgpack

from io import BytesIO

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect('tcp://10.144.207.139:5555')

socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")

while True:
print ("Waiting for message")
message = socket.recv()
print ("message received: " + str(message) )
```

Comment: It seems you already have Python code to receive a message, so what's the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 How to convert to numpy array received data ?

Comment: Does the msgpack module which you import have some kind of "unpack" method which you intended to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

key is the :

```
print ("Waiting for message")
message = socket.recv()

deser_message = msgpack.unpackb(message, raw=False)

image = np.array(Image.open(io.BytesIO(deser_message[0])))
cv2.imshow("received image" , image)
cv2.waitKey(1)

print ("message received: "  , counter)
counter += 1
```